# Access to all cells in table view (Xcode, iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I use custom cells with buttons. On editing mode I need buttons to disappear. 
I call this method when editing status changes:

```
-(void)setButtonsVisibility:(BOOL)visibility {
    UIButton *currButton;
    for (int i = 0; i <= [array count] - 1; i++) {
        currButton = (UIButton *)[_tableView viewWithTag:10000+i];
        if (currButton) {
            [currButton setAlpha:visibility];
        }
    }
}
```

It works great. But this method don't work for cells that not visible now. For example, when there are more than 10 cells in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're reusing the cells properly, then the only UITableViewCells that exist in memory will be the 10 that are visible.

Easiest solution would be to just add a `BOOL` flag to the `UITableViewDataSource` instance that indicates whether to show or hide the buttons.  Then the ~10 that are visible will be updated properly by your existing method, and in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which will be called after you scroll, you can set the alpha property on the button to the flag's value.

Comment: I made it your way. But there is something strange. When I turn on editing mode, then move table up or down, then turn off editing mode, buttons that was not on screen when I turned on editing mode are not became visible. I don't know why method from my first post isn't working... All buttons have tag = 10000 + indexPath.row.

Comment: I'm sorry. Your advice work like a charm. There was a mistake in my code. Thank you very much!!